# 'WORD': 'char [20]' differs in levels of indirection from 'unsigned short'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm completely new to c++ and I've been handed a data analysis program that I want to run. I essentially only have one error to get through (after having eliminated hundreds) but I can't seem to crack what this one means. This code runs perfectly fine on a Mac but mine is Windows. I'm also using Visual Studio.

This is the script where the error occurs. The error is at the line that reads:

```
typedef char WORD[NWORD];

/***********************************************

 Header file with generally useful Macros

 Version for  C++

 As written here, can be included "indescriminantly"
 without danger of multiple definitions.  Nothing will
 be inserted if content has already been included.

 Program must also include stdio.h and stdlib.h, but these
 are almost universal.

 *********************************************************/

#ifndef  MCRO

#define MCRO

#define PI  3.14159265358979

#define AND     &&
#define OR      ||
#define IS      ==

#include <cstring>


#define STRCHK(x,y) if(strlen(x) >= (y)) {printf("String %s too long\n",x);exit(0);}

// This is a macro for checking reads for overrunning memory allocation
// It is a function  void STRCHK( char* x, int y) that quits program if
//  string is filled beyond its capacity y.
//  NOTE:  No ';' is needed to end line with this Macro.


#define SKIPLINE(x)   fscanf(x,"%*s%*[^\n\r][\n\r]")
// This macro skips a line in reading the file (pointer) x
// It works regardless of whether \n or\r is used for new lines

#define NWORD   20
#define NPHRASE 200

typedef char WORD[NWORD];       // Utilities for construction of arrays of strings
typedef char PHRASE[NPHRASE];

#endif
```

Comment: What is with all the Cisms?  If you are writing C++ why not use C++?

Comment: @NathanOliver: "I've been handed a data analysis program"

Comment: Can you show the file this was included in when the error occurred?

Comment: There's a whole bunch of .cpp files and header files.

Comment: "when the error occurred"

Answer (score 2):

On Windows the symbol "WORD" is defined by a #define buried in <Windows.h>  [bad practice but history requires forward compatibility, right]

You need to use something other than "WORD" for your own definition.

This [Microsoft Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) will show you some of the other dangerous symbols.